# Remove underline from table of contents (titlesec package)

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, underline

quick question.

So I tried to customize my section formatting, and wanted to underline sections (among other things).

BUT! I'm using the `titlesec` package, and ToC is seen as a section from what I gathered... So the question is: can I "remove" the underline from the Table of Contents, yet keep it for sections?

Pretty sure I can make it work with `sectsty` but it doesn't go well with some other packages I load...

Here's my MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\section}{\Large \bfseries}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{\underline}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you put your titleformat after the TOC then the TOC itself is not underlined but the following sections are.

Comment: Damn, the solution was actually so easy! I usually don't like putting editing commands in the document itself but eh, as long as it works... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You also may decide that unnumbered sections will not be underlined (so also,index, bibliography, &c.) using the  `nemberless` key in the preamble, like this: 
`\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}{\Large \bfseries}{}{0em}{}` This beind said, underlining section titlegd with typewriters…